# TYPO3 9: Domain routing and redirects with site management

Tags: .htaccess, typo3, typo3-9.x

How can I configure my TYPO3 website by using the new *Site management* module to match these tasks:

1. domain.tld should be the base
2. www.domain.tld should redirect to domain.tld
3. SSL should be enforced as well

With earlier versions of TYPO3 i have achieved this by creating two domain records: one for domain.tld and the other for www.domain.tld, defined as permanent redirect to https://domain.tld. SSL was enforced by htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)| [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http%1://domain.tld/? [R=301,L]
```

In the *Site management* module of TYPO3 v9 I defined 'https://domain.tld' as *Entry point*. This works fine so far, but requests for 'www.domain.tld' or 'http://domain.tld' are resulting in a redirect error. I have created the domain records for 'www.domain.tld' and 'domain.tld' as well.
Meanwhile I have changed the entry point to '/', at least the requests for 'www.domain.tld' are working now. 
But what is the best practice to achieve the goals by using the *Site management* and *Redirects* modules?

Comment: Do you need a site configuration for www.domain.ltd or do you just want to redirect www.domain.ltd to domain.ltd?

Comment: The latter: a redirect from www.domain.ltd to domain.ltd.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to redirect all www-traffic to non-www traffic, you can handle that without any TYPO3 configuration. You can redirect all requests from www to non-www with rewrite rules in your webserver configuration directly. In my opinion, there is no need to let TYPO3 handle the redirect at all. It is also faster, as there is no need to "boot" TYPO3 just to handle the redirect.

For apache (example):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1$1 [R=301,L]
```

To redirect non https to https:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://domain.ltd/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Mikel, the redirect works like clockwork! Unfortunately, I still have the problem that requests for http: //domain.tld do not redirect to https: //domain.tld. 
In combination with the following rule this does also the trick to enforce SSL by requests for http://domain.tld:
    `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}     !^443$`
    `RewriteRule (.*)  https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`

Comment: I updated my answer and added another rewrite to force https. It is the same as yours, but more general (HTTPS instead of SERVER_PORT).

Comment: Thank you very much! I kept the Server Variables in the RewriteRule to effect all domains in the TYPO3 instance: `RewriteRule ^(.*)  https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`. But theres still one problem. A request for `http://domain.tld/` redirect to `https://domain.tld/` as espected; if you extend this URI to `http://domain.tld/homepage` (valid page segment) TYPO3 responds with an 404 instead of `https://domain.tld/homepage` . Is this caused by the RewriteRule or by TYPO3?

Comment: I can't answer that. What happens, if you enter https://domain.tld/homepage in your browser directly?

Comment: When I enter domain.tld/homepage, TYPO3 tries to load https://domain.tld/index.php and ends up with an error message:
`Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: #1225709595: The Fluid template files "" could not be loaded. | TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\View\Exception\InvalidTemplateResourceException thrown in file /typo3_src/typo3_src-9.5.4/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/View/TemplatePaths.php in line 730. Requested URL: https://domain.tld/index.php`